# Returning the sum of 1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n Series

Tags: java, recursion, methods, sum

I would like for you to help me correct the output on this method. The recursive version returns what I need, but the non_recursive version does not return the same result. Here is my code:

```
public static double sum_nr(int n){
    int result = 1;
    for(int i=n-1; i>0; i--){
        result += 1/i;
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Is the string a palindrome or not? ");
    String test = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_r(test));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + isPalindrome_nr(test));
    System.out.println("What is the sum of n number: ");
    int test2 = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Answer: " + sum_r(test2));
    System.out.println("Answer: " + sum_nr(test2));
}
```

Recursive version when `n = 10` is `1.6179775280898876`

Non-recursive version `n = 10` is `2.0`

I want these two to both match up. Can you help me?

Comment: What about the recursive version - mind sharing it with us or should we guess ?

Comment: Please add the `sum_r()` method definition to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use an `int` for `result`. Declare it to be a `double`. Also, do the division using a double literal for the numerator. These two problems were conspiring to create the bad behavior. In particular, `1/i` was integer division and was evaluating to 0 for all `i` > 1. If you use `1.0/i`, that won't happen because `i` gets promoted to a `double` before the division.

```
public static double sum_nr(int n){
    double result = 1;         // <-- first change
    for(int i=n-1; i>0; i--){
        result += 1.0/i;       // <-- second change
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Represent maths department!

Answer (score 0):

`1/i` will be 1 for i==1, and 0 for any i > 1 since you're using `int`. Hence, your result is 2.

Use a `double` or `float` instead to do your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The following two versions return the same result:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(sum_nr(10)); //3.928968253968254
        System.out.println(sum_r(10));  //3.928968253968254
    }

    public static double sum_nr(int n){
        double result = 1;
        for(int i = n; i > 0; i--){
            result += 1.0/i;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static double sum_r(int n){
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 1.0/n + sum_r(n-1);
        }
    }
```